# Why animation doesn't work in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Decided to raise the level of knowledge of JS according to the book Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja (second edition)

There's an example for working with circuits and kavakami the example animation. I rewrote but it does not work with the browser does not see errors.

```js
function animateIt(elementId) {

  var elem = document.getElementById(elementId)
  var tick = 0

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (tick < 100) {
      elem.style.left = elem.style.top = tick + 'px'
      tick++
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer)

    }
  }, 10)
}
animateIt('box1')
```

```html
<div id="box1">First Box</div>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function animateIt(elementId) {

  var elem = document.getElementById(elementId)
  var tick = 0

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (tick < 100) {
      elem.style.position = "absolute";
      elem.style.left = elem.style.top = tick + 'px'
      tick++
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer)

    }
  }, 10)
}
animateIt('box1')
```

Comment: Thx for javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<div id="box1" style="position: absolute;">First Box</div>
```

By default a `div` has `position: static` which causes the `left` or `top` style property to not affect the element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
 /* Unchanged JS */ function animateIt(t){var e=document.getElementById(t),n=0,a=setInterval(function(){n<100?(e.style.left=e.style.top=n+"px",n++):clearInterval(a)},10)}animateIt("box1");
```

```css
/*
 * For the `top` and `left` property to work, your element needs
 * to have a `position: relative` or `absolute` or `fixed`
 */
#box1 { position: relative; }
```

```html
<!-- Unchanged HTML --> <div id="box1">First Box</div>
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working fine, but for the div to move you need to set its style position.

in this case i set it to realtive and have not changed anything in your code

```js
function animateIt(elementId) {

  var elem = document.getElementById(elementId)
  var tick = 0

  var timer = setInterval(function() {

    if (tick < 100) {
      elem.style.left = elem.style.top = tick + 'px'
      tick++
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer)

    }
  }, 10)
}
animateIt('box1')
```

```css
div{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">First Box</div>
```